# List type signatures

Tags: haskell

This makes sense:

```
test :: [[Int]]
test = [[]]

main = print test
```

But why does this compile (and run)?

```
test :: [[Int]]
test = []

main = print test
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`[[Int]]` is list of lists (of Int's) and

- `[[]]` - list with one empty list inside
- `[]` - empty list

Answer (score 4):

The type of `[]` is polymorphic, i.e. `forall t. [t]`, meaning it represents an empty list of any type `t`. Since `test` is of type `[[Int]]`, we can unify `t ~ [Int]` and therefore `[]` is an empty list of type `[[Int]]` also.